# Why jQuery's .change() event only fires on right-mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, onchange

I am having trouble with jquery's `.change()` event when I am modifying an input element. Supposedly, this event will fire every time I have live changes on the said element. But in my case it only fires after I have pressed the right-click button. Here are my codes on `laravel` framework:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="verifyPassword"><h4>Verify Password:</h4></label>
    {{ Form::password('password',array('class'=>'span3 form-control', 'id'=>'verify-password', 'placeholder'=>'Verify Password')) }}
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#verify-password" ).change(function() {
          alert( "Text Changed!" );
        });
});
```

Hope someone could help me find the mess and get me with perfect solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For text fields, the `change` event is not fired until the element loses focus (and a change has been made to its' value).

From the API:

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

If you need to know when the value changes immediately, use `keyup` or `keypress`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the upfront insight and solution. I met the perfect solution with your suggestion to use `keypress()` event. Thanks!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, just a small glitch buddy. The `keypress`, `keyup` and `keydown` events don't fire after certain key was pressed. It waits for next key to be pressed before it fires. In this case, I can't compare two variables from two elements correctly. It's like if I type `test` on first password field, I have to type 5 characters to the verify password field before the values will be validated correctly. How may I reconcile this?

Comment: `keyup` should work as you need: http://jsfiddle.net/wd38m/1/. If you type `password` in the field, you should see the flag change to `true` as you type the final `d`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks again sir. My bad for not trying the .keyup() event. Thank you again. Now it works perfectly.