# Why I can't compare two strings correctly using jQuery's .keypress(), .keydown() and .keyup() events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, events

I want to validate two inputs using `javascript`. I am using `jQuery's .keypress()` events to directly verify the inputted values. Here's my code in `laravel` framework:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword"><h4>Password:</h4></label>
    {{ Form::password('password',array('class'=>'span3 form-control', 'id'=>'password', 'placeholder'=>'Password')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="verifyPassword"><h4>Verify Password:</h4></label>
    {{ Form::password('password',array('class'=>'span3 form-control', 'id'=>'verify-password', 'placeholder'=>'Verify Password')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-danger hide" id="alert-verify-password-remove">
        Password don't match!
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove alert-icon-padding-remove"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-success hide" id="alert-verify-password-ok">
        Password matched!
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok alert-icon-padding-ok"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#verify-password" ).keypress(function() {
          // get password value from first password field
          var pwd = $('#password').val();
          // get the 2nd password value from the verify password field
          var vPwd = $('#verify-password').val();
          // verify the values if they are matched
          // if matched then show match alert | hide unmatch alert
          if (pwd == vPwd) {
                $("#alert-verify-password-ok").removeClass('hide');
                $("#alert-verify-password-remove").addClass('hide');
          } // else, show unmatch alert | hide match alert
          else {
                $("#alert-verify-password-remove").removeClass('hide');
                $("#alert-verify-password-ok").addClass('hide');
          }
        });
});
```

The problem I got is that, If for example I typed on `#password` field is `test` then in `#verify-password` field I have to type `tests` or any character after the 4th before the validation validates it to be correct/matched. Here's the picture that shows what is happening.

[image]

As you can see, I have to type 5 (`tests`) characters instead of 4 (`test`) before it identify that the values are the same. Can someone give me insights what's happening here and at least give me suitable solutions for this. Thank you.

Comment: I answered this in a comment on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055587/why-jquerys-change-event-only-fires-on-right-mouse-click#comment37092503_24055631 - you need to use `keyup` not `keypress` in your scenario.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, I haven't receive the notification from your reply to my previous question. I'm on a hurry that's why I created new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `keypress` occurs before the string is actually changed (And thus you can cancel string change)

Use `keyup` event for those tests

```
...
 $( "#verify-password" ).keyup( function() {
...
```

`keyup` is fired after string is changed, so the values in test will be the same as the values you see

Comment: My bad for not trying the .keyup() thing lol. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keyup`, because its triggert after `keypress`. You can see this for example [`here`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events)

```
$( "#verify-password" ).keyup( function() {
```